# Instrumental Variable for Moderator (Causality)

Tags: interaction, causality, instrumental-variables

I only know of instrumental variables that causally influence the independent variable and, through the independent variable, are associated with the outcome (making it possible to assume the causal effect of the IV on the DV).

However, is it also possible to use an instrumental variable to investigate the causal role of a moderator? Do you know any examples of papers (preferably social science papers) that did something similar?

[image: Illustrative Model]

Thank you!

Comment: It will be possible. But I don't know of any examples (I thought about shift-share instruments but they seem different). So I guess that in this setting the moderator variable is included as an interaction term with the other explanatory variable?